# Files not showing up because looking at root but I think I specify the root!

Tags: html, apache, vhosts

I'm working locally and I always specify files as /files.jpg or whatnot so the server will always know to look at the root level to find the files. That way if I'm on a subpage it won't choke. But locally the files do not show up. My file structure is apache2/htdocs/name_of_folder. name_of_folder is my "root". I then modify my virtualhost file so when I enter localhost/name_of_folder it will show my site. I specify the DocumentRoot so I thought when I say localhost/name_of_folder that is working at the document root?

In httpd-vhosts.conf I have it set to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/name_of_folder"
    ServerName localhost/name_of_folder
    ServerAlias www.localhost/name_of_folder
    ErrorLog "logs/name_of_folder_log"
    CustomLog "logs/name_of_folder_access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @PeeHaa - I get the following for an image...127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2011:09:48:16 -0400] "GET /rss_28x28.png HTTP/1.1" 404 211

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#servername) and [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#serveralias) directives. They have nothing to do with files or paths. They are the **domain** name that identifies the web site (together with an optional port if not 80). If you want to move your document root, you have to edit the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive.

Comment: G. Vicario - But I am using this apache to have multiple sites. So I specify the documentroot to be apache2/htdocs and then inside of htdocs I have the site folders and those are the roots. Can I have multiple documentroots for each site? I thought I could only have one?

Comment: @rich - I'm not sure I follow you. If you want multiple sites, you create multiple `<VirtualHost>...</VirtualHost>` blocks. You don't configure everything in a single site.

Comment: G. Vicario - Right...I understand I would need multiple VirtualHost blocks but the only one I have in there now is not working. Wouldn't me saying     DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/name_of_folder" in the virtualhost (see my code above) get it to work?

Comment: @rich - Nope. If `name_of_folder` is the document root, typing `/name_of_folder` in your browser looks for `/opt/local/apache2/name_of_folder/name_of_folder`.

Answer (score 0):

You may not do this in that way. The directive `ServerName` is not supposed to get an URL but a domain name. Set the root to the parent folder, deny all access to it using `<Directory>` and allow access to you subdirectory to get it work.

Comment: in my httpd.conf I have ServerRoot "/opt/local/apache2" and DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs". And inside of htdocs are directories of site names. So one cold be name_of_folder. I want to then be able to say localhost/name_of_folder and it knows that is the root. Not sure what you mean by setting the root to the parent...I thought I did that by doing the documentroot above. Why would I want to deny access?

Comment: @rich: Apart from concrete directives: What are you exactly trying to archive?

Comment: @marc-Sorry marc not sure what your question means. Locally my images are not showing up because I specify /file.jpg in my html code. It works fine in production.But locally the images just don't show up because I am assuming it is looking for the image in the root because I specified a /.I specified the documentroot to be apache2/htdocs in my httpd.conf file. I did that because I have multiple sites I want to work on. So I guess the file is looking in the htdocs folder for my image and of course it is not there. So I thought a VirtualHost would tell it to change its documentroot for that site

Comment: Yes, but `VirtualHost` only works with domain names and not with paths. So you should choose the subdomain as PeeHaa answered. Then the browser will see the correct root.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of doing:

```
ServerName localhost/name_of_folder
ServerAlias www.localhost/name_of_folder
```

Create a subdomain:

```
ServerName subdomain.localhost
```

Comment: is there something else I need to do in order to allow for subdomains? I can't figure it out. I did what you said with subdomain.localhost I also tried subdomain.127.0.0.1 and it keeps redirecting to my isp page not found

Comment: @rich: Have you restarted the apache services? To do this go to: Start -> Run -> and type in services.msc. Find the Apache service and restart it

Comment: yes I am on a Mac (apachectl graceful). I think it as to do with my host file. I added 127.0.0.1  subdomain.localhost and it now points to the htdocs directory...the second virtualhosts stack...`<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/subdomain"
ServerName subdomain.localhost
</VirtualHost>`

`<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>`
It is like it is skipping right over the first virtualhost. Maybe because I have two 127.0.0.1 declared in my hosts? `127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1 subdomain.localhost`